# gradle java-platform works only for modules in public repo but not for my own modules from private repository

Tags: gradle

I implemented 'java-platform' from gradle to centralize version management. It does work nicely for public dependencies but fails to resolve versions for my own modules. Platform looks like this:

```
group = "cz.sc"
version = "1.0"

plugins {
    `java-platform`
    `maven-publish`
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://gitlab.sc ..../maven")
        ....
    }
}
publishing {
    publications {
           ... // works
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    constraints {
        //ours
        api("cz.sc:base-models:0.0.23")
        api("cz.sc:bank-models:0.0.16")
        api("cz.sc:servlet:0.1.4")
        api("cz.sc:generator:0.0.13")
        //foreign
        api("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.5.9")
        api("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.7")
        ....
    }
}
```

And its consumed:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("cz.sc:jvm-platform:${versionOrSnapshot("0.0.1")}"))

    implementation("cz.sc:base-models:0.0.23") // OK
    implementation("cz.sc:bank-models") // not working
    implementation("cz.sc:servlet") // not working

    implementation("cz.sc:private-api-models:${versionOrSnapshot("0.0.9")}")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    ...
}
```

It works for all modules, which are not mine `cz.sc...`, It does not work for any modules which are created by me and published to my gitlab maven repo. When I provide version directly, it will work.

```
rootProject.name = "bank-api"

include("jvm-platform")
project(":jvm-platform").projectDir = file("../jvm-platform")


includeBuild("../bank-models")
includeBuild("../base-models")
includeBuild("../servlet")
```

I also tried with (and without) include and includeBuild. It does not work either.

Edit:

From `./gradlew dependencies` it seems that

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for null/main.
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.21
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.21
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.21
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21 (*)

|    +--- cz.sc:base-models:0.0.23 -> project :base-models (c)
|    +--- cz.sc:bank-models:0.0.16 (c)
|    +--- cz.sc:servlet:0.1.4 -> project :servlet (c)
|    +--- io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.5.9 (c)
```

`+--- project :jvm-platform` is obsolete, even if its correct `project` dependency, however `productionRuntimeClasspath` uses same jvm-platform and that one it up to date